# Getting angles for rotating $3$D vector to point in direction of another $3$D vector

Tags: vector-spaces, 3d

I've been trying to solve this in Mathematica for $2$ hours, but got the wrong result.

I have a vector, in my case $\{0, 0, -1\}$. I want a function that, given a different vector, gives me angles DX and DY, so if I rotate the original vector by an angle of DX around the X axis, and then rotate it by an angle of DY around the Y axis, I'll get a vector with the same direction as the given vector.

(I want this so I could input angles to SolidWorks to rotate a part so it will satisfy a constraint I defined in Mathematica.)

Comment: You're starting with a vector along the z axis. To get where you want to go, it's super easy to rotate first about the x-axis, and then about the z-axis. Is there some reason you're making it hard on yourself by rotating first about x, and then about y?

Comment: An x-z answer is acceptable too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need a 3×3 rotation matrix $E$ such that

$$ E\,\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix} = -\hat{k} $$

This rotation matrix consists of two elementary rotations

$$ \begin{aligned} 
  E & = {\rm Rot}(\hat{i},\varphi_x){\rm Rot}(\hat{j},\varphi_y) \\
    & = \begin{pmatrix} 
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & \cos\varphi_x & -\sin\varphi_x \\ 
0 & \sin\varphi_x & \cos\varphi_x
\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 
\cos\varphi_y &0 & \sin\varphi_y \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
- \sin\varphi_y & 0 &  \cos\varphi_y
\end{pmatrix}
\end{aligned} $$

This is solved with

$$  \varphi_x = - \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{y}{\sqrt{x^2+z^2}} \right) \\
     \varphi_y = \pi - \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{x}{z}  \right) $$

if $\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}=1$ is true.

### Verification

use $(x,y,z) = (\frac{1}{2}, \frac{3}{4}, \frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}) = (0.5, 0.75, 0.4330) $ to get

$$  \varphi_x = - \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\frac{3}{4}}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^2+\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)^2}} \right) = -0.8481 \\
\varphi_y = \pi - \tan^{-1} \left( \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}}  \right) =  2.2845$$

With a rotation matrix

$$ E = \begin{pmatrix} -0.6547 & 0 & 0.7559 \\ -0.5669 & 0.6614 & -0.4910 \\ -0.5 & -0.75 & -0.4330 \end{pmatrix} $$

and $$ \begin{pmatrix} -0.6547 & 0 & 0.7559 \\ -0.5669 & 0.6614 & -0.4910 \\ -0.5 & -0.75 & -0.4330 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0.5 \\ 0.75 \\ 0.4330 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{pmatrix} $$

---

<sub>**NOTICE:** Some combinations of $(x,y,z)$ will *not* yield the correct result because it won't be possible with the specific rotation sequence used.</sub>

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! Two things: 1. I think you misunderstood me (my language was vague): I want to rotate the {0,0,-1} vector into the given vector, not the other way around. 2. I want to know how you did the "This is solved with" step. Where did arctan come from? I want to know how to make this step for future calculations.

Comment: You know the $E^\top$ above will rotate the $\hat{k}$ vector into $(x,y,z)$.

Comment: What you are looking for are called Euler angles, and so search for "finding Euler angles" to get things like this [paper](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~sbbh653/publications/euler.pdf) which explains how to extract them for various rotation scenarios.

Comment: Also, to solve in your case you just create the system of equations from the rotation $\vec{v}=-E\hat{k}$ or in expanded form $$\begin{aligned} &x = -\sin\varphi_y \\ y &= \sin\varphi_x \cos\varphi_y \\ z &= -\cos\varphi_x \cos\varphi_y \end{aligned}$$. Divide the last two to get $\varphi_x$ and then combine them to get $$\sin\varphi_y = -x \\ \cos\varphi_y = \sqrt{y^2+z^2} $$ which is used to get the $\arctan$ values. I prefer those becasue the [`Atan2()`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2) function works miracles.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, if you don't mind rotating about the y and z axes, we can do it like this. Let's take a typical vector like (6,3,2) so the overall length is 7. You want to rotate a vector from the z axis into this orientation. First you look at the angle whose cosine is 2/7...that's how far down you have to come from the z axis. So you rotate about the y axis by that amount. Now you just have to swing around the z axis by the angle whose tangent is 3/6.

I think that's all you need to line up your vectors.[image]